# Finding the maximum mean

Tags: r

I've got a data set of American football statistics, where there's a column for the player's name and one for his rating for that game. I want to find which player had the highest average rating out of the data set. How can I do this without manually making a subgroup of each player's mean?

Comment: You can start by posting a dataset example using `dput(head(dat, 20))`, where `dat`  is your data, an expected output example and, hopefully, the code you've tried. Edit your question, please, this is the typical example of the to broad a question that gets downvoted and then closed.

Answer (score 3):

if df is your data frame:

```
df %>%
  group_by(player_name) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(rank, na.rm = TRUE)) # to add new column
```

or `summary(df, mean = mean(rank, na.rm = TRUE))`

Then you can arrange the dataset by this mean rank by adding

```
arrange(df, desc(mean))
```

You would get arranged dataset with the highest value of this average at the top